# Hypernym for reading a book and listening to an audiobook

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, hypernyms

I want to state that "I've read 10 books this year", but the books in question can be both dead-wood books and audiobooks. Is there a verb that works here in place of 'read'? Maybe something like 'learned' or 'ingested' (eww)?

Comment: Why does there have to be a single word for a distinction that's only a few decades old? "Audiobook" is not what you call a traditional English word.

Comment: I've known blind people who say things like *"I've just read a good book"* when obviously what they mean is they've listened to someone else reading it out loud. If there were a suitable verb that *didn't* imply using one's eyes, I think they'd have latched onto it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers [Braille](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille).  Blind people can read.

Comment: Two BTWs: This is an unusual case in that "print book," which might otherwise seem to be a retronym, dates back to the mid-sixteenth century. And in post-Hellenistic Greek prose, the verb ἀκούω, *hear,* could also mean *read.*

Comment: @Doc: Only one of the four blind people I've known reasonably well has been able and willing to use Braille with anything like the fluency sighted people use for books. They tend to jump at the chance to use audio books, screenreaders, *human* readers, etc., because it's just so much quicker and easier.

Comment: Would *perused* work?

Comment: @FumbleFingers the plural of anecdote is not data; but in my case, ten out of ten blind people I know are fluent in Braille (in defense of your hypothesis, they are all older than me (45+ years) and there were no good audiobooks and other assistive tech when they were alphabetized.)

Comment: Stick with "*read*". See the answer from @Third News.

Comment: This is perhaps technically unrelated, but I think it is relevant as another example of a similar type of situation. Many deaf people that I know will use the sign for "talk" in conversation instead of "sign". "I was talking to so-and-so...", "Talk to you later", "I need to talk to my mom later...", and so on. What they mean is that they were signing with so-and-so, or whatever, but they use the sign for "talk" instead.

Comment: I'm really sorry but this question is plain, old dumb. **Reading and listening are two very distinct activities**.  Must it be said? Is there one word for riding a bicycle and riding a horse? People seem to go over the cliff on questions like these without *pausing to think*. And Braille and sign language are reading and reading respectively.

Answer (score 22):

Maybe:

> I've *gone through* 10 books this year.

Or

> I've *gotten through* 10 books this year.

Or

> I've *finished* 10 books this year.

Or

> I've *made it through* 10 books this year.

Or

> I've *[devoured](http://literatehousewife.com/2013/08/the-cuckoos-calling/)* 10 books this year.

Comment: *Consumed* would also work, in the same vein as "devoured", but with less enthusiasm behind it.

Answer (score 16):

'Read' seems applicable as a term for both audio and visual books because the etymology of '[**read**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=read&allowed_in_frame=0)' does not  suggest 'with your eyes only'.   Secondly, The blind commonly refer to 'reading', and even 'seeing' with their fingers.

Comment: +1. This is the best answer, IMO.  If you need to distinguish types of reading (and that includes the two ways you mentioned, plus more) then do so.  If not, use "*read*".

Comment: I actually disagree with this.  While it's true that the blind "read" with their fingers, they're still involving words on a physical object (even e-books qualify, because they're on the physical device).  *Listening* to a book does not require a physical object of any sort.  Similarly, you can read in isolation, but listening requires another person be involved (even if they're separated in time and space).

Comment: @Bobson, I think we need to look not only at the root of a word but the original intent with respect to the times. I think we can easily confuse our present day with historical fact -books were damn rare in 1580s, and the "having knowledge gained from reading," was not indicative of ever seeing a book in your lifetime.  Interestingly,I was doing research on Revolutionary America, and if you were caught traveling with paper (a rare resource), it was an indication that you were a spy -I can't imagine what they did if you had your 'vade mecum'

Comment: @ThirdNews - Books were rare, paper was rare, but words on physical objects weren't, necessarily.  I actually originally write "words on a page", but corrected myself to the more general case.  Inscribing words on stone or clay and then later reading them off again is a very ancient art.

Comment: @Bobson, please show me your reference for the word 'read' that reflects your opinion -naturally one that predates 1580

Comment: @ThirdNews - I think we're arguing different things.  I'm saying that the word "read" in its *current* sense implies text of some sort.  It can be used in that sense on historical actions, even if they happened before the word acquired that meaning.  Thus listening to a book being read by someone else is not reading it yourself because you're not interacting with the text.  I think you're saying that because "read" comes from a root which doesn't have anything to do with text, then accessing a book in any form can be considered "reading" it.

Comment: @ThirdNews - As a counter example: If I'm reading a book to my child at bedtime, can I say that he/she "read" the book?  If I record myself, and the child listens to the recording, have they "read" the book?  I'd say not, because they're being *read to*, and not doing the reading themselves.

Comment: @Bobson please review the original etymology

Comment: @ThirdNews - Please review what I wrote.  I'm discussing the *current* usage.  The etymology is informative but not defining.  We can take this to chat if you like.

Comment: @Bobson. and therein lies the rub why language develops

Comment: You can read with your eyes (text) or your fingers (Braille) but last time I checked you can't read with your ears. For pete's sake.

Answer (score 8):

A jargonized word for using content of any kind is ***consume***. Typically, however, this word is used in reference to others, like ***"Our users consume 25 hours of video, 55 hours of audio, and 500 pages ..."*** You probably don't want to say ***"I consumed 10 books last year."*** It just sounds weird in this context.

So I suggest, as other have, to simply say ***read*** or ***completed*** or ***gotten through***. The actual media used is far less important than the knowledge you gleaned from it.

Comment: Consume seems to imply you ate the book.

Comment: @Oldcat It is jargon in this context. This particular use is specific to those in the content delivery industries, such as newspapers, video and audio production, etc. Specifically, these would be companies like The huffington post, iTunes division of Apple, and Universal Studios film division.

Answer (score 6):

Why use just the one word? Why not say ''I've read or listened to 10 books this year''?
The disadvantage of words like 'learned', 'studied', 'ingested', 'digested' is that you don't necessarily do all these things when you read/listen to a book. You might skim, scan, dislike or simply not get whatever it is you've been reading/hearing. You could use 'engaged' or 'interacted' but it would sound, to my ear at least, a little pretentious.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that they were reasonably good books, you could say that you *enjoyed* them.

Comment: If it were fiction, I would certainly choose enjoyed over any of these other choices. It's already quite natural to say in the context of reading alone.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **[taken in](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/take-in)**? Several of the definitions of this term could apply

> - to admit; receive
> - to include; comprise
> - to understand; comprehend

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

> I've *studied* 10 books this year.

Comment: That probably wouldn't work if your reading material was mainly [potboilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potboiler) or other "entertainment-only" books.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed. I like Elian's answer best thus far.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use: [assimilate:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Assimilate)

> - To incorporate and absorb into the mind: assimilate knowledge.

- I have assimilated the content of 10 books this year

Comment: I don't think I'm particularly dim, but I must admit that I have assimilated only a small fraction of the books I have read.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just say, "I completed 10 books this year" or "I finished 10 books this year." The format, whether it's visual or auditory doesn't matter.

Comment: If you say either of those, then it's unfortunately ambiguous whether you're an average reader or a really productive writer.